# How does this C program work?

Tags: c, unix

```
void child(int *fd) {
    int j , x; 
    for(j = 0; j < 10; j ++) {
        scanf ("%d", &x);
        if(x % 2 != 0)
            write(fd[1], sizeof(int), &x);
    }
    close (fd[1]);
}

void parent(int *fd) {
    int v, r = 0;
    while(read(fd[0], sizeof(int), &v) != 0)
        r = r + v;
    printf("%d\n", r);
}

int main(void) {
    int s, fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    s = fork();
    if(s == 0)
        child(fd);
    else parent(fd);
}
```

I think that the above program create a pipe fd and place two file descriptors, one each into the arguments fd[0] and fd[1] ==> then It create a new process

- It launch the child function if s = 0 ==> the program input 10 integers ==> if an integer is odd ==> It write &x bytes from the buffer pointed to by sizeof(int) to the file associated with the open file descriptor, fd[1] ==> it deallocate the file descriptor indicated by fd[1]
- It launch the parent function if s != 0 ==> if &v = 0 ==> it displays the value of &v.

But I still not sure about how this program works, please feel free to correct or to give more details. Thank for the help !

Comment: Note that you should check return value of *scanf*. Now, if it reads non-number, it will return 0, and leave *y* unchanged (and therefore potentially uninitialized in this code), and leave the non-number unread (so it will keep returning 0 and not reading anything).

Comment: You cannot delete content like that. People have answered it. Destroying your question invalidates their answer. If you don't want it online, you shouldn't have asked the question. By posting it here you have irrevocably and perpetually licensed the content to the site. Please leave it in place.

Comment: @user3305709 If there is a very good reason why you want to see this content deleted, please flag for moderator attention using the "Other" option. Then clearly explain why this needs to be removed. Though perhaps you only require disassociation. Deleting it like this will only end up hurting you, if you are suspended because of it.

Answer (score 2):

You're close.

Your description of how the child process works is correct.

The parent process reads each number from the pipe. It's not testing whether `z` is 0, it's testing whether `read` returns 0, which it does when it has reached EOF (i.e. the child has closed the pipe). And it's not displaying the value of `&z`, it's adding up all the values of `z` and displaying the total when it reaches the end.

Answer (score 1):

As written, the code is a bit odd because the second and third parameters of the read and write functions seem backwards. It's just weird to "write &y bytes from the buffer pointed to by sizeof(int)" because sizeof() anything isn't a buffer.

If you swap those two, then the child process reads integers from the console and writes the odd ones to a pipe back to the parent, who reads them, sums them and prints the sum at EOF.